# Dynamic json property deserialize

Tags: c#, json

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to deserialize a json, that has a dynamic property (for example - **UserRequest::567)** the property name can be any value and the UserRequest object contains other json properties that are of interest to me

I tired writing a class and I don't know what to do with that property. What are the best practices for coping with a problem like this?

```
{
    "objects": {
        "UserRequest::567": {
            "code": 0,
            "message": "created",
            "class": "UserRequest",
            "key": "567",
            "fields": {
                "ref": "R-000567",
                "org_id": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The question is what are the best practices to read through this kind of a json string?

Thank you

Comment: You are on the right path, have you ever tried to use NewtonJson to deserialize your son object?

Comment: I have tried to serialize the whole json 

var createRequest = CreateRequest.FromJson(jsonString)

But how do i dynamically get the UserRequest property name? It can be any name.
For example  - UserRequest::567, UserRequest::568 and so on.

Comment: are you talking about to deserialize a dynamic json string?

Comment: Yes.

How for example i should read the code/message and other properties if my UserRequest is dynamic?

Comment: Use `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `Deserialize` this using `Newtonsoft.Json`, here are the classes:

```
public class CreateRequest
{
    public long code { get;set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("class")]
    public string class1 { get; set; }

    public string key { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("ref")]
    public string refe { get; set; }
    public string org_id { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, CreateRequest> objects { get; set; }
    //The 'string' key in the dictionary is the 'UserRequest::567'
}
```

Then to `Deserialize` use:

```
var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonObject).objects.Values;
```

Comment: Glad to help you!